# How to calculate $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_c|1+z+z^2|^2dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let c denotes the unit circle centered at the origin in C then $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_c|1+z+z^2|^2dz$ where the integral is taken anti clockwise along C equals

1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 3

   I tried this by considering the properties of the complex numbers $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$, by considering $z=Re^{i\theta}$ and by substituting $z=x+iy$ but i didn't get how to solve this

Comment: What difficulties do you have after expanding $(1+z+z^2)(1+\bar z+\bar z^2)$?

Comment: by expanding $(1+z+z^2)(1+\bar{z}+\bar{z}^2)$ i get the expression containing $z\bar{z}$. i don't know how to integrate further

Comment: You said that you had noticed $z\bar z=|z|^2$. Why get stuck?

Comment: Have you considered any answers to the [ten questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/442290/priyanka) useful and *accepting* some of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $z\bar z=|z|^2$.
Expanding $$
(1+z+z^2)(1+\bar z+\bar z^2)
$$
one gets
$$
(1+\bar z+\bar z^2)
+(z+|z|^2+z|z|^2)
+z^2+ z|z|^2+|z|^4.
$$
Now let $z=e^{i\theta}$ ($z$ is on the unit circle!) and use the linearity of integrals.

Comment: Now I understood the solution. Even after knowing the property i got stuck to integrate after expansion. By substituting $=re{^i\theta}$ i can solve. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers